# S3 Management Console: Unable to copy/move object after anonymous uploading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have created bucket with Upload/Delete permissions granted to everyone.
Objects were uploaded anonymously to the bucket using simple HTTP PUT requests (i.e. curl).
By checking object properties in S3 Management Console we've detected that uploaded objects don't have "Owner" property.

Attempts to use S3 Management Console to copy/move objects to another location even within the same bucket are failed with error: "The following objects were not copied due to errors from: <bucket>"

Appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: That's one reason among many why anonymous uploads are a bad idea.  You can't fix this.  The only solution is to delete the objects.

Comment: What's the bucket policy and what permissions do your IAM user have? It sounds like a permission issue.

Comment: You might be able to [take ownership of the objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004200/amazon-s3-how-do-i-download-objects-owned-by-anonymous-user/28389577#28389577). If not, delete them.